# Convert int array to string using C

Tags: c, arrays

So I have something like this:

```
int array[5] = {1, 6, 2, 4, 4};
char string[255];

/*do something*/

printf("%s\n", string);
```

Output should be:

```
[1, 6, 2, 4, 4]
```

I really don't know where to start...

Comment: Which step exactly is unclear to you? You can use `sprintf` to write numbers to a char-buffer and adding the other characters is not that complicated either

Comment: Why ```[1, 6, 2, 5, 5]```? If this is the array ```{1, 6, 2, 4, 4};```.

Comment: @Lucas the output is an char string so
string[0] = "["
string[1] = "1"
string[2] = ","
....
string[14] = "]"

Ah, sorry. I wrote it bad

Comment: Well, you say you don't know where to start. The first step would apparently be to assign `'['` to `str[0]`. Thereafter you need to at least try to write an algorithm of your own. But I can't see anything of that in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. demonstrates the use of `strcpy()` and `sprintf()`
4. avoids the use of 'magic' numbers
5. lets the compiler calculate the number of entries in the array[]

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main( void )
{
    int array[] = {1, 6, 2, 4, 4};
    char string[255] = {0};

    /*do something*/
    strcpy( string, "[" );
    for( size_t i = 0; i < (sizeof(array)/sizeof(int)) -1; i++ )
    {
        sprintf( &string[ strlen(string) ],  "%d, ", array[i] );
    }

    sprintf( &string[ strlen(string) ],  "%d", array[4] );
    strcat( string, "]" );

    printf("%s\n", string);
}
```

a run of the proposed code results in:

```
[1, 6, 2, 4, 4]
```

Comment: only comment is that it has a fixed size output buffer but doesnt defend against overruns, clearly works here but since you say you allow for arbitrary size array ...

Answer (score -1):

You need to convert the integer into equivalent char using the ascii table subtraction and then strcat to the main string

Answer (score -1):

To convert the array to a string, you should use `snprintf`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

char *join(char *dest, size_t size, const int *array, size_t count) {
    if (size == 0) {
        return NULL;
    }
    if (size == 1) {
       dest[0] = '\0';
       return dest;
    }
    size_t pos = 0;
    dest[pos++] = '[';
    dest[pos] = '\0';
    for (size_t i = 0; pos < size && i < count; i++) { 
        int len = snprintf(dest + pos, size - pos, "%d%s",
                           array[i], (i + 1 < count) ? ", " : "]");
        if (len < 0)
            return NULL;
        pos += len;
    }
    return dest;
}

int main() {
    int array[5] = { 1, 6, 2, 4, 4 };
    char string[255];

    if (join(string, sizeof string, array, sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array))) {
        printf("%s\n", string);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How about making `join` return `NULL` if the `snprintf` returns negative number, and then in `main`, test the return and don't call `printf`? Currently it looks like it might end up calling `printf` on a string that isn't `\0`-terminated if that happened, so probably segfault.

Comment: @alaniwi: good point. `snprintf` is highly unlikely to return -1, except on legacy systems where it could indicate that the output exceeds the available space, which is non-standard conforming. Answer updated.